# Orthogonal Projections

Tags: linear-algebra

> Consider the real inner product space $$C([-1,1]) = \{ f : [-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} : f \text{ is continuous } \}$$ with its usual inner product $$\langle f,g\rangle=\int_{-1}^{1} f(t) g(t) \, dt.$$ Find the orthogonal projection of $f=|t|$ onto the subspace $W = \text{Span}(\{1,t,t^2\})$.

This is a question on the practice final for my linear algebra class. I've been able to do orthogonal projections when they are real vectors onto a plane, but am confused how to go about this one.

I know $f(\textbf{-t})=f(\textbf{t})=\textbf{t}$.

Isn't $\textbf{t}$ already in $W$?

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes, $\;t\in W\;$ , **yet** $\;|t|\notin W\;$ ...

Comment: I know how to go through the gram-schmidt process with vectors of real values, but I'm confused how to go about it with this function.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p = proj_{W} f$, then by Gram-Schmidt an orthogonal basis is

$$\{ 1, t, t^2 -1/3\}$$

Thus without normalizing $$p =  \left < 1, |t| \right >1/2 + \left <t, |t| \right > \frac{t}{2/3} + \left <t^2 -1/3,|t| \right>\frac{(t^2 - 1/3)}{8/45}.$$

The integration needed are

$$\int_{-1}^{1} |t| dt = 2 \left(\frac{1}{2}(1)(1) \right) = 1 \quad \text{area of triangle.}$$

$$\int_{-1}^{1} t|t| dt = 0 \quad \text{odd integrand.}$$

\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^{1} t^2|t| dt &= \int_{-1}^{0} t^2(-t) dt+  \int_{0}^{1} t^2(t) dt\\
&= \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}\\
&= \frac{1}{2}.
\end{align}

or use the fact that the integrand is even, and $|t| = t$ for $t \in [0,1]$ to evaluate $$2\int_{0}^{1}t^3 dt = \frac{1}{2}.$$

The rest follows from some simple rules of integration.

Comment: I got p &= 1+ /frac{t^2} {2}

is this correct?

Comment: Okay cool, also what resources can I use to learn how to format better for this site. It uses LaTeX right? I'm new here and don't know how to make my questions all purtty-like.

I thought I formatted the above comment correctly... apparently not?

Comment: @Nameless: I don't think your $p$ is a projection; $p(1)$ should be one, but according to your definition it will have nonzero component on $t^2$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami, well actually, I didn't normalize, but the OP should. My answer might have mislead him.

Comment: After doing the integration, over and over and over again, the basis is now correct.

Comment: Is that basis really orthonormal?  Isn't $\int_{-1}^1 (t)(t) \, dt = 2/3$?

Comment: @Muphrid, I am making a lot of careless mistakes today aren't I? I'll change the word.

Answer (score 2):

The orthogonal projection of $|t|$ onto the linear space spanned by $\{ 1,t,t^{2}\}$ is the unique polynomial $p(t)=a+bt+ct^{2}$ such that
$$
                 (|t|-p,1)=(|t|-p,t)=(|t|-p,t^{2})=0.
$$
That's the simplest definition of orthogonal projection. So you need to solve for $a$, $b$, $c$ such that
$$
\begin{align}
        0 & =\int_{-1}^{1}(|t|-a-bt-ct^{2})\,dt = 1-2a-2c/3, \\
        0 & =\int_{-1}^{1}(|t|-a-bt-ct^{2})t\,dt = -2b/3, \\
        0 & =\int_{-1}^{1}(|t|-a-bt-ct^{2})t^{2}\,dt = 1-2a/3-2c/5 .
\end{align}
$$
The equations are fairly straightforward, provided I didn't mess up one or more integration terms. Note: the odd terms integrate to $0$, which includes the integrals of $bt$, $|t|t$, $-at$, $-ct^{3}$, $bt^{3}$.