# Orthonormal set problem

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products, orthonormal

A)For the First three member of $(x_0, x_1, x_2, ... ) $ with respect to $$x_{j}(t)=t^{j}$$
in $[-1,1]$ , use the inner product function below to make them orthonormal.
$$\langle x,y\rangle =\int_{-1}^{1}x(t)y(t)dt$$

what I have done so far, using the product function, trying every 2 pairs of $x_j $, but they dont get zero for $(x_0,x_2)$,

B) Should the norm of all $ x_j$ become equal to zero? Considering Norm Function below I suppose  $$\lVert x \rVert=\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}$$

C) What diffrence would it make if we consider them like below
$$x_{1}(t)=t^{2},x_{2}(t)=t,x_{3}(t)=1 $$

Comment: I just answered this question  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/791187/orthogonal-projections/791192#791192, at least partially

Comment: Sorry but I still don't get it , how is that in solve my problem here

Comment: I wish people would not overlook such jarring problems as using inequality signs for inner product when reviewing edits...

Comment: in (B) for Orthonormal sets the norm of $x_j$ must be 1 (not 0), and in (C) you let $x_0=1$ and you can't get $x_3=1$.